# How to use 32-bits libraries in 64-bits R?

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, 32bit-64bit

I built a server with Ubuntu 64-bit and installed R 64-bit and a function.so 32bit library. When I try to load this library in R it shows me this error:

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Is there any way to use a 32-bit library in 64-bit R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can link a 32 bit .so file to a 64 bit executable. You can run 32 bit programs under a 64 bit OS, but this means that both the executables and the libraries they depend on are 32 bit. To be able to use the library you will have to recompile it using a 64 bit compiler.

I this is not possible, you could opt to run 32 bit R on your 64 bit OS. This would however limit your memory usage, as 32 bit only allows you to address around 4 GB of memory for one R process.